# C# Unit Testing (Xunit and Moq) - Test an interface and its implementations separately

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, moq, xunit

I want to separate the unit tests for testing the interface behavior itself and the additional business behavior of the implementations.

```
public interface IIncrementor
{
    void Increment();

    int Count { get; }
}

public class AIncrementor : IIncrementor { /* Implementation */ }
public class BIncrementor : IIncrementor { /* Implementation */ }
```

To ensure the correctness of the business behavior of an interface I need to check all according implementations against my defined unit tests. Of course every implementation has its own additional behavior to test, but I don't want to repeat myself over and over again.

My current solution was to create an abstract test-class with an abstract property for the subclasses to implement.

```
public abstract class IIncrementorTest
{
    protected abstract IIncrementor Incrementor { get; }

    [Fact]
    public void WhenIncremented_ThenCounterHasCorrectValue()
    {
        var oldCount = Incrementor.Count;

        Incrementor.Increment();

        Assert.Equal(oldCount + 1, Incrementor.Count);
    }
}

public class AIncremetorTest : IIncrementorTest
{
    protected override IIncrementor Incrementor => new AIncrementor();

    [Fact]
    public void WhenSomeAdditional_ThenCheckSomething() { /* More test */ }
}

public class BIncremetorTest : IIncrementorTest
{
    protected override IIncrementor Incrementor => new BIncrementor();

    [Fact]
    public void WhenSomeAdditional_ThenCheckSomething() { /* More test */ }
}
```

But that leads to some problems, e.g. when a test case needs to build an instance differently which is very likely to happen. Would you suggest to create abstract properties for these cases?

```
protected abstract IIncrementor IncrementorForCheckingSomething { get; }
```

Or is there a best practice approach which solves this interface-test problem comprehensively?

Comment: Why are you trying to test a mock?

Comment: This question is not clear.

Comment: @Nkosi I want to check all implementations of an interface against a unit test; if my business rule implies that the amount of items in a store must increment as I call the Save-method I want to test this behavior on the interface "itself" which means that I must gather all the implementation-classes reflection-wise (mocked) and let them pass the unit test.

Comment: It is the `mock the implementation-types` that is not clear. Those would not be mocks they would be implementation instances. Just use reflection and to get all the implementations and create an instance of each to run your test on. Also the question is a little broad as There is no indication if the implementations have dependencies that would also need to be mocked.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, you want to write one set of tests for your interface, and apply those tests to any classes which implement that interface.

You could use reflection to find all the types in your assembly which implement the interface with something like this:

```
var interfaceType = typeof(IIncrementor);
var types = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
.SelectMany(a => a.GetTypes())
.Where(t => t.IsClass && interfaceType.IsAssignableFrom(t));
```

and instantiate all of those types. This could be tricky if they don't share a common constructor signature; but would work for the examples in the question using the default constructor...

```
foreach(Type t in types)
{
    yield return (IIncrementor)Activator.CreateInstance(t,null);
}
```

Put that code in a method with return type `IEnumerable<IIncrementor>` and give that method the attribute [MemberData](https://andrewlock.net/creating-parameterised-tests-in-xunit-with-inlinedata-classdata-and-memberdata/) to pass these instances into each of the tests.

Comment: I do not think this is what they were after.  It seems they wanted to write each test one time, and then see them displayed in test explorer once for each implementer with their own pass/fail status.  Unfortunately, Reflection cannot create tests.

They tried to use derived test classes, but that made it difficult to provide custom mocks to the tests for various implementers.  I.e. if the test for implementer B should use mock B for some other interface involved in the test, the derived test class would not be able to provide that without some additional mechanism.

Comment: @Daniel Reflection cannot create tests, and that wasn't what I was proposing. The MemberData approach allows you to dynamically parameterise tests, and I was using Reflection as the source of those parameters. Using this approach I would expect each instance to be displayed separately in the test explorer with individual pass/fail status, without the need for writing individual tests. The display name might not be helpful, so perhaps a better split could be achieved with the "MemberData" method supplying text-based values; but the concept is sound.